# Updating a particular sub document in mongo db php

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a collection in mongo db called EmployeeTbl with document like

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a8d47d8d2ccda11fc004d91"),
"EmployeeNumber": "9883456787",
"FirstName": "Sana",
 ...
  "ContactDetails": [
 {
   "ContactTypeId": "04596c6f-82e6-8f00-e3a9-1f3199894284",
   "ContactType": "Phone",
   "ContactTypeValue": "99456789756" 
},
 {
   "ContactTypeId": "71d0152c-293f-4c6f-2360-bbdfe368eacb",
   "ContactType": "Phone",
   "ContactTypeValue": "9894567890" 
  } 
 ]
```

}

I am trying to update a sub document inside ContactDetails and I have written below code. It is not updating the existing one. Instead of updating, it adds new sub document. 
Please help me !!!

```
     public function updateContactDetailsForItsSubDocument()
{
             // $bulkbatch = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);  

              $subDocumentContactDetails = array(
                            "ContactDetails" => 
                                      array(
                                      "ContactType" => $this->ContactType,
                                      "ContactTypeValue" => $this->ContactTypeValue
                                   )
                               );

              $this->collection->update(
                            array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), 'ContactDetails.ContactTypeId'=> $this->ContactTypeId),
                            array('$set' => $subDocumentContactDetails)
                                );

             // $this->manager->executeBulkWrite($this->collection, $bulkbatch);  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$subDocumentContactDetails` variable so that it uses the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) for updating an embedded document:

```
$subDocumentContactDetails = array(
    "ContactDetails.$.ContactType" => $this->ContactType,
    "ContactDetails.$.ContactTypeValue" => $this->ContactTypeValue
);

$this->collection->update(
    array(
        "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), 
        "ContactDetails.ContactTypeId" => $this->ContactTypeId
    ),
    array("$set" => $subDocumentContactDetails)
);
```